# Mysql LIKE query with WHERE clause - (InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, innodb

Please advise on my query which runs without errors. When searching by name the row is not returned if Active = 0 in the table.

However if I search by suburb the row is returned despite Active = 0 in the table. I have tried NOT LIKE but with the same outcome. Which is the best solution for the WHERE clause to run on the whole query.

*(With corrections suggested)*

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  table name
    WHERE  Active = 1
      AND  (name LIKE '%$searchq%'
              OR  town LIKE '%$searchq%'
              OR  Keyword LIKE '%$searchq%'
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use brackets in conditions, not two times WHERE:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE 
(Name LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Town LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Suburb LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Keyword LIKE '%$searchq%') 
AND Active = 1
```

Advice:

1. Try not to use variable direct in query to prevent sql injection.
2. If active is a flag 0 or 1 you can use integer or bool in your database and then use in query just Active = 1.
3. I think more popular is use column names as snake case(e.g. number_of_people)

Comment: The query has a syntax error.  `OR Keyword' (<- here it is) LIKE '%$searchq%') AND Active = '1'`

Comment: Try now. I've coppied from your query with "Keyword' LIKE"

Comment: Try not to use var dirrect in query to prevent sql injection.

Comment: I added some advices on my answer. I hope this helps. Regars.

Answer (score 0):

You had an extra WHERE there, and possibly (although I don't think so?) a matter of precedence:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Active = '1' " AND ( Name LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Town LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Suburb LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Keyword' LIKE '%$searchq%' );
```

Comment: The qeury has a syntax error.. `Active = '1' " (<- here it is) `

Comment: Type corrected & second WHERE clause removed but still returning rows WHERE Active = 0. Thank you for the quick responses ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your query. You should correct it

```
select * from <table-name> where (name like '%$searchq%' or suburb like '%$searchq%' or town like '%$searchq%' or keyword like '%$searchq%' ) and active = 0;
```

You don't type the word where twice.